# angular 8 map does not exist on type '{}'

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, rxjs, angular8

I have a simple application which gets its data from a firebase/firestore database.

in the getAlbums (get all) method the map gives an error.
(error: 'map' does not exist on type '{}'

list-component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

// Firebase
import { AlbumService } from './../album.service';
import { Album } from './../album.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-album-list',
  templateUrl: './album-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./album-list.component.scss']
})
export class AlbumListComponent implements OnInit {
  albums: Album[];

  constructor(
    private albumService:AlbumService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getAlbums();
  }

  getAlbums() {
    this.albumService.getAlbums().subscribe(data => {
      this.albums = data.map(a => {
        return {
          id: a.payload.doc.id,
          ...a.payload.doc.data()
        } as Album;
      })
    });
  }
}
```

app-module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

// Firebase
import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire';
import { AngularFireDatabaseModule } from '@angular/fire/database';
import { environment } from './../environments/environment';
import { AlbumListComponent } from './albums/album-list/album-list.component';
import { CommonModule } from "@angular/common";


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    AlbumListComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    CommonModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig),
    AngularFireDatabaseModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Already imported the map oporator (in list component) and added the commonmodule (in app module)

Comment: Can you share what `this.albumService.getAlbums()` does ?

Comment: There's a difference between the `map` operator from rxjs and the `Array.prototype.map` method you are attempting to call on an object...

Comment: this.albumService.getAlbums().subscribe should return Array, then use can use 'map' on arrays, not on objects.

Comment: Seems you will need to post what `AlbumService. getAlbums()` does. You shouldn't need to import the rxjs map operator here if `getAlbums` truly returns an array.

Answer (score 1):

You must check if every item of your array is null or undefined because if you try to map a null object it will give you an error. Try to add this condition `if(!a) return null;`

```
getAlbums() {
    this.albumService.getAlbums().subscribe(data => {
      this.albums = data.map(a => {
        if(!a) return null;
        return {
          id: a.payload.doc.id,
          ...a.payload.doc.data()
        } as Album;
      })
    });
  }
```